# Implementing Animejs script in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a Login page in React.js and I want to add some animation effects using animejs. How can I add the anime script in class or functional component in React?

Here is the anime I'm trying to implement in react.js:

[Click here to see in CodePen](https://rb.gy/s9hegy)

Answer (score 0):

You can install anime.js for React by running "npm install react-animejs"
From there you can import the library like this:

```
import ReactAnime from 'react-animejs'
const {Anime, stagger} = ReactAnime
```

After that you will have access to an  component that you can use like so:

```
<Anime
initial={[
{
  targets: "#Box",
  keyframes: [
    {
      translateX: 50
    },
    {
      translateY: 50
    },
    {
      translateX: 0
    },
    {
      translateY: 0
    }
  ],
  // easing:'spring',
  duration: 3500,
  loop: true
}
]}
>
<Box />
</Anime>
```

You can read more about using anime with React on the official [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-animejs) and [github](https://github.com/jmdisuanco/jm-react-anime) pages